# In my controller I can't read a value from a form in my template

Tags: ember.js

I have the following templates defined in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div>
        <p>{{outlet}}</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="registration">
    <form autocomplete="on">
        First name:<input type='text' name='firstName'><br>
        Last name: <input type='text' name='lastName'><br>
        E-mail: <input type='email' name='primaryEmailAddress'><br>
        Password: <input type='password' name='password' autocomplete='off'><br>
        <button type='button' {{action 'createUser'}}>Register</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    createUser : function () {
        var name = this.get('firstName');
    }
});
```

When I click the button on my form the 'createUser' function is called. However, I am unable to read any of the values from the form.

My view is as follows:

```
App.UsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'registration'
});
```

I appreciate it makes the association between my controller and the template, however in this scenario I'm not seeing any other value - does it offer me anything else?

Comment: did you get an answer for this? if so please post it..

Answer (score 2):

The reason being you did not bind any values from the input fields to any of the property in the controller, you can use Ember's built in [Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) as follows

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="registration">
  <form autocomplete="on">
    <!-- 
        The valueBinding="firstName" binds the value entered by the user in the
         textfield to the property firstName in the controller
    -->
    First name:{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}<br>
    Last name:{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}<br>
    E-mail:{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="email"}}<br>
    Password: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="password" type="password"}}<br>
    <button type='button' {{action 'createUser'}}>Register</button>
  </form>
</script>
```

Now can get the access

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  createUser : function () {
    alert(this.get('firstName'));
    alert(this.get('lastName'));
    alert(this.get('email'));
    alert(this.get('password'));
  }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QEfCG/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it is not working for me, my value remains undefined (http://jsfiddle.net/k7cLV/). Also is there an alternative approach to using Ember.TextField - as much as possible I would prefer to retain pure HTML.

Comment: Check the fiddle in the answer